# SDL Tridion 2009 vs 2011 vs 2013

Tags: 2011, 2013, 2009, api, architecture

Major and Minor Releases of **SDL Tridion** has new features and module updates, What are all the features added or removed from the SDL tridion **2009 to 2011** and **2011 to 2013 SP1**.

Is there any way we can find the comparison of API updates, Technology updates, Platform updates, Architecture Update,.etc.,.
Overall how can we find the Functional and Technical updates among these versions?.

Comment: There's some good answers below. I'm curious about what makes you think that 2013 is a minor release. 2013 SP1 is a minor release, but not 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope the below picture helps with a very high level comparison of various SDL Tridion version from R5.x through 2013

[image]

Comment: It's a good overview, but maybe a little simplified and biased towards the newer versions. For example, Experience Manager has been around for all of those versions (was just named SiteEdit back then), and it's been possible to extend the CME for all of those versions too (just harder and less structured)

Comment: Agreed that its simplified..

Answer (score 7):

You can find 'Release notes' associated with each version of SDL Tridion in the online documentation.

For example, these can be found on the [PDF documentation downloads](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-6EECAC56-AC01-4AF4-9310-32316846C798) page in the online documentation for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

This document is described as:

> The release notes describes new features, changed features, what has
>   been fixed in this release, and what the known issues are.

In addition to this, the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 docs has a [What's new in SDL Tridion](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-01ED0398-34BB-47BC-A428-7E2570AFDFF6) section with pages describing the functionality introduced or changed in SDL Tridion 2013 (incl. SP1) and SDL Tridion 2011 (incl. SP1)...

And the SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 docs have a [What's new in SDL Tridion](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A7162AA8-60B2-4BF5-BA44-A0084E2E6603) section with pages covering SDL Tridion 2011 (incl. SP1) and SDL Tridion 2009 (incl. SP1).

This documentation is quite detailed, including things such as (for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1):

- The replacement of Jetty with Tomcat for the Content Manager Search
- The introduction of the Import and Export Service
- deprecation of `RenderComponentField()` in templating
- Changes to Multimedia Component creation through APIs

Hopefully these cover the 'Functional and Technical updates' that you require.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer:  Tridion 2013 SP1 is the latest and greatest SDL release and built using the same Architecture as 2011.  Content Porter is completely rebuilt and performs much faster and more reliable.  In Tridion 2013 the integrations between other SDL products is better (such as Smart Target) and the GUI performs faster.  As Jonathan mentions, the documentation has all the juicy details, but in general, don't think twice about it and make a plan to get to 2013 SP1.

Today there is not any good reason to upgrade from Tridion 2009 or 5.x to a Tridion 2011 system.  You will have much more support and find more resources online for solving Tridion 2013 SP1 issues and challenges than Tridion 2011.

This year we expect to see Tridion 2015 released, and if you upgrade to Tridion 2013 SP1 then you will be behind the main release by only 1 version.  Also, today the majority of customers are on 2013 SP1 or moving to it very soon.